# Any way to disable drag in mobile view for react-beautiful-dnd?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I used react-beautiful-dnd package in my project. Where I want to disable the drag option in mobile view(e.g window.innerwidth < 768 or something), but it will work properly in desktop view.
I tried using the prop isDragDisabled, but it is not working.
Here is what I have done so far,

```js
function ProductItem({
  objectId,
  name,
  availability,
  images = [],
  idx,
  category,
}) {
  const [isMobileView, setIsMobileView] = useState(window.innerWidth < 768);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => {
      setIsMobileView(window.innerWidth < 768);
    };

    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <Draggable
      draggableId={`${category}-${idx}`}
      index={idx}
      isDragDisabled={isMobileView}
    >
      {(provided) => {
        return (
          <div
            key={idx}
            className="item"
            ref={provided.innerRef}
            {...provided.draggableProps}
            {...provided.dragHandleProps}
          >
            <img src={images[0]} alt="restaurant" />
            <div>
              <h3 className="title">{name}</h3>
            </div>
            <ProductAvailability id={objectId} availability={availability} />
            {provided.placeholder}
          </div>
        );
      }}
    </Draggable>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is probably because, when the window size changes, the `isDragDisabled` prop is not being updated. I suggest you, to use the [`Droppable`](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/blob/master/docs/api/droppable.md) component to render the `Draggable` component conditionally, based on the window size.

Comment: Droppable component is already the parent of this ProductItem. So, If I render conditionally, the Draggable component won't be displayed. But it's not the expected behavior.